# <a> tag crumbles on fadein

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following **HTML**

```
 <table>
      <tr>
        <td id="portrait">
            <div id="photo"></div>
        </td>
        <td id="slide">
            <div id="slider" class="inactive">
                <a id="something" class="thisthing" onclick="executethis()">some link here</a>
            </div>
        </td>

        </tr>
    </table>
```

**CSS**

```
td{
  width:120px;
  height:100px;
  top:20px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#slide{
  border: none;
  padding-left:30px;
}
#slider{
  border: none;
  padding-left:30px;
  background-color:green;
  position:relative;
  height:100%;
  opacity:0;
  width:0px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.thisthing{
  cursor:pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 white, 0 1px white, 1px 0 white, 0 -1px white;
  color: green;
}

#something{
  position:absolute;
}
```

JS

```
$('#portrait').mouseover(function(){
    $('#slider').animate({
    opacity: 1,
    width: "300px"
  }, 2000, $.noop);
});
```

As you can see, the link crumbles on it's way in with fadeIn. How can I avoid that and maintain it as "part" of the opening div? What I really want is for it not to escalonate on top of everything http://jsfiddle.net/c6FE2/1/

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans He has an example.  Who the hell cares about terminology.  Sometimes we dont' know the correct terminology.  This is for coding.  Stachexchange might have an English site that you could freely join.

Comment: @KingKongFrog actually, they do!   http://english.stackexchange.com   Haha...

Comment: @KingKongFrog Terminology matters so we can communicate effectively. If he knew the term was "wrap", he probably would have found "nowrap" on his own.

Comment: @JasonP the point is, he didn't.

Comment: @KingKongFrog True, and there's nothing wrong with that, but you jumped on Mike for informing him of the correct terminology.

Comment: on a secondary note, it also helps people browsing the list of open SO questions in determining whether they can help answer a question. The code in the question seemed intelligent enough to assume the poster had at least heard of text wrap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you just don't like how it wraps... Try something like this:

```
.thisthing{
  cursor:pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 white, 0 1px white, 1px 0 white, 0 -1px white;
  color: green;
  white-space: nowrap; // nowrap should do it
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c6FE2/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/MDrqv/)

Add `white-space:nowrap` to `#something`

Comment: Although a demo is good, please consider adding its text to the answer to make the answer self-sufficient. Otherwise, the value of your answer would go down if the server that you used for the demo is no longer available.